# Push to github using gitextensions The server host key does not match the one putty

Tags: git, git-extensions

I have been using gitExtensions to handle github repositories successfuly for quite a while.
Today, when pushing a version I am receiving the following message

```
"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" push --recurse-submodules=check --progress "gitHub" refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
WARNING - POTENTIAL SECURITY BREACH!
The server's host key does not match the one PuTTY has
cached in the registry. This means that either the
server administrator has changed the host key, or you
have actually connected to another computer pretending
to be the server.
The new rsa2 key fingerprint is:
ssh-rsa 3072 d5:2c:63:d9:bc:75:9d:de:b1:4e:36:28:9f:7a:9c:39
If you were expecting this change and trust the new key,
enter "y" to update PuTTY's cache and continue connecting.
If you want to carry on connecting but without updating
the cache, enter "n".
If you want to abandon the connection completely, press
Return to cancel. Pressing Return is the ONLY guaranteed
safe choice.
Update cached key? (y/n, Return cancels connection)
```

typing y or n does nothing and I need to abort

How can I fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not going to be able to write a full answer here, but it is very possibly relevant to you that [GitHub changed their RSA SSH host key](https://github.blog/2023-03-23-we-updated-our-rsa-ssh-host-key/) in late March.

Comment: Thanks. I followed this by still it does not work. I opened a ticket with GitHub and waiting on them

Answer (score 0):

Run `putty.exe` (usually installed in `%ProgramFiles%\PuTTY` but downloading it to another directory and running from there should work, too), SSH to the hostname you're pulling from and accept the host key when prompted. (You don't need to actually log into the machine, so the username doesn't matter.) Git Extensions uses PuTTY internally, so once PuTTY has "remembered" the host it will also work from Git Extensions.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Last June I tried different ways to fix it. At one point of time, I was able to get a different error (sorry, I did not take good notes) about SSL TLS. The Git ext is running in this case on a Windows 7 computer (and I have to keep it this way for other reasons) and I had to find a way to let Windows 7 use this protocol. I found out how to do it in the registry and since then, everything is working fine.